# Data type mismatch in criteria expression - Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

```
SELECT p.productid, p.productname, p.productprice,
SUM(s.noofitems) AS TotalNumberOfItems
FROM soldvia AS s
INNER JOIN product AS p
ON p.productid = s.productid
WHERE 'TotalNumberOfItems' > 3
GROUP BY p.productid, p.productname, p.productprice
ORDER BY p.productid;
```

The question for this query states, "For each product that has more than three items sold within all sales transactions, retrieve the product id, product name, and product price (no nested queries).
I really have been having trouble with this question and hoping that someone can shed some light on a mistake I may be making. Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using the query design window or the wizards?

Comment: The error tells it all. Adjust to:  
WHERE TotalNumberOfItems > 3 or: WHERE SUM(s.noofitems) > 3

Comment: I asked a friend from class to help and they told me to use the totalnumberofitems. I changed it to HAVING sum(s.noofitems) > 3 because it would not allow me to use WHERE and SUM together. It worked! Thank you so much for the feedback! I really appreciate it!!